# template is missing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to solve this error "template is missing " in ruby on rail
my controller is

```
class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    @title = "Ruby on Rails"
    @website = "www.9lessons.info"
  end
end
```

my html page is

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title><%= @title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to <%= @website %></h1>
    Addition : <%= 100 + 300 %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you copy the exact error? and state what url you were trying to access?

Answer (score -1):

your def method name needs to match your view name.

i.e

```
def index
end
```

must be index.html.erb

```
def hello
end
```

would be hello.html.erb

```
def world 
end
```

would be world.html.erb

if not you will get a missing template because it is looking for that specific name.